# limits of notify-send in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, notify-send

before 18.04 i used to have the following command that shows the last 10 lines of a file in notification

`notify-send -u critical "test" -t 7000 $(tail -10 /tmp/Follow-test)`

in Ubuntu 18.04 it shows only 6 lines and stay forever till i click it

did the behavior of the command change?